# What kind of ID is more safer

Tags: php, mysql, social-networking

I'm developing a small social network and my Database "USERS" has 2 id's 
the first one is ID_USER = is primary key and autonumerica like 1,2,3,4,5.
the another one is ID_UNIQ = it's generate with php uniqid()
What do you recommend to use?, is that I saw that for example facebook use long id's like profile.php?id=100003565125387.., althought is not the same because uniqid() generate id's with letters and numbers, so in this case what kind of id would be safer?._

Comment: It's not the value of the id that makes things safe, it's how you handle it in your code

Comment: Security through obscurance is never a good way. I personally just use the primary key for ultimate validation, and this id is never shown anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have also developed a similar kind of project. And for that I used the something like ID_USER. And it worked fine. But the problem is that the user can easily find out someone else's id. But to make sure that other people can't log into to someone else's account I have used session. But if you feel that it is not safe enough then you can use uniqid. It depends on you and how you handle it. This is just my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a matter of 'safety' per se. However, you can use `uniqid()` if you plan on allowing users accessing your website without creating an account. You assign this randomly generated user id, and store in a cookie. When user decided to signup, this unique becomes that user's permanent id, and all history of browsing and other activity (including temporary shopping baskets) will be automatically 'transferred' to that user. When given uniqid does not belong to a registered user, and was not used by, let's say' two weeks, you simply erase it. I hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

You are free to use any uniquely identifying value.... the security is gained not from how you identify your users but from properly authenticating them a limiting their access to resources they are authorized to see. I would only suggest using a value that does not change over time.